# Setting {WSL::Bash} as default shell throws an error in cmder

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, conemu, cmder

```
note: backend error output: -v: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
-v: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file


ConEmuC: Root process was alive less than 10 sec, ExitCode=0.
Press Enter or Esc to close console...
```

This is error i am getting.

Also i have set the fish shell as default shell in WSL.

Comment: We need a little more information on this. Maybe amend your question to include the settings you are using for that default task. I use cmder every day with wsl and zsh as default shells so this 100% works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For WSL1 on windows 10 build later than 1909 (yes wsl2 is available to me but for corporate reasons i cant use it)

Try setting your command to `wsl.exe -new_console:d:C:\_stuff\code -cur_console:p5` and the task parameters to `/dir "c:/_stuff/code" /icon "c:/_distros/ubuntu/ubuntu1804.exe"`

You may need to change the file locations to make the command and parameters suitable for your setup. `c:/_stuff/code` is where i keep all my repositories and `c:/_distros/ubuntu` is where i have installed ubuntu.